# Testing components with a request for rtk-query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-testing-library, rtk-query

I have started testing my React app and I have run into a problem - I can't test the components that are loaded from the server. Requests for uploading data are made via rtk-query, and I only know how to test this on axios.

Code request:

```js
export const postApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'getAllChallenges',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: urlDomain }),
    tagTypes: ['Challenge'],
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getAllChallenges: build.query<IChallenge[], string>({
            query: () => ({
                url: urlGetChallenges,
            }),
            providesTags: res => ['Challenge']
        }),
        getChallengeById: build.query<IChallengeDetails, string>({
            query: (id: string) => ({
                url: urlGetChallengeById + id,
                headers: {
                    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
                    signature: localStorage.getItem('signature') || '',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            }),
            providesTags: res => ['Challenge']
        }),
        getChallengeMembers: build.query<IChallengeMember[], string>({
            query: (id: string) => ({
                url: urlGetChallengeMembers + id,
                headers: {
                    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
                    signature: localStorage.getItem('signature') || '',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            }),
            providesTags: res => ['Challenge']
        }),
        acceptChallenge: build.mutation<IChallengeMember[], string>({
            query: (id: string) => ({
                url: urlAcceptChallenge + id,
                headers: {
                    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
                    signature: localStorage.getItem('signature') || '',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Challenge']
        })
    })
})
```

The code of the component that is being loaded:

```js
const Challenges: FC = () => {
    const { data: challenges, isLoading } = postApi.useGetAllChallengesQuery('')
    const { loginStatus } = useTypedSelector(state => state.login)
    return (
        <MainWrapper dataTestid='challenges-page'>
            <Popup />
            {loginStatus && <CreateChallenge />}
            {isLoading && <Loader />}
            {challenges && challenges.map(challenge =>
                <ChallengesItem data-testid='challenge-item' key={challenge.challenge_id} challenge={challenge} />
            )}
        </MainWrapper>
    )
}


export default Challenges
```

Comment: What testing have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [msw](https://mswjs.io/) to mock your api - that's what we use in the Redux Toolkit codebase to test RTK Query.

Comment: Can you provide examples of how testing with msw will help?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage honestly, I don't want to do that - `msw` just released a major with a lot of apis changed, and all answers showcasing `msw` 1 have been invalidated. I give answers about the library I maintain (Redux Toolkit/RTK Query), but for third party tools I'm gonna link you to their documentation which will explain it better than I can do and will stay up to date. This was not a "how do I do this specific thing with msw" question, but a question on how to test apis with RTK Query, and all I can tell you is that we use msw, it's a great tool, but I'm not in the position to teach that.

Comment: Be that as it may, answers should be standalone without relying on external links. If all this question is, is a "Recommend me a testing library" then it should be closed as a 'recommendation question'.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage look, obviously this question and answer have helped other people find an industry standard solution to their problem. 
I am not going to copy the "getting started" guide from the MSW documentation, and if that webpage ever goes down it will be a strong indicator not to use that library anyways.
If you insist on it, I can remove the link, write out "mock service worker" and add one or two more sentences to comply with rules, but all that happened as a result of that is that you wasted a package maintainer's time they are spending to help their userbase.